# Finite field and its element with symbols [Sage / Python / ...]

Tags: linear-algebra, finite-fields, sagemath, python

I have a finite field $T=GF(2^3)$, normal basis $(a, a^2, a^4)$ and polynomial $f$ from field $T$, which contains unknown variables / symbols.
Is it possible to get vector with coordinates of f in normal basis?

Example in Sage:

```
T.<x> = GF(2^3)
V = T.vector_space()
alpha = x^2+1
normalBasis = [ alpha^(2^i) for i in range(T.degree()) ]

W = [ b._vector_() for b in normalB ] 
normalBasisVector = V.span_of_basis(W)

def linearCombination(coords, basis):
    return sum( [ coords[i] * basis[i] for i in range(len(basis)) ] )

a,b,c = var('a','b','c')
gB = [a,b,c] # vector g in normal basis
g = linearCombination(gB, normalB)

normalBasisVector.coordinates(g) # I'd like to get back g in normal basis (that is (a,b,c))
-> TypeError: can't initialize vector from nonzero non-list
```

If this is impossible in Sage, is it possible in any other Mathematic / Programming Language e.g. in Python?

I hope I presented my problem clearly. If you didn't get anything, feel free to ask me.

Thanks,

Denholm

Comment: Could you recall what do you mean by "normal basis" in a finite field ?

Comment: Let's take it as a definition. Let $K = GF(q)$ a $T = GF(q^m)$. A normal basis for $T$ over $K$ has a form $(a, a^q, . . . , a^{q^{m−1}})$, where $a$ is a suitable element and $a ∈ T$. The normal basis exists iff $(a, a^q, . . . , a^{q^{m−1}})$ is lineary independent.

Comment: I encounter the same problem. Have you solve it? You can contact me at hxk123@yeah.net. I hope to discuss with you.

Answer (score 1):

Finite fields don't mix well with Sage's symbolic ring, the place where
Sage's symbolic variables, like `a`, `b`, `c` in the question, live.

The trick is to do the linear algebra over `GF(2)` and to go back
and forth between matrices over `GF(2)` and matrices over `ZZ` when
we need to involve symbolic variables.

Setting (as in the question).

```
sage: T.<x> = GF(2^3)
sage: T
Finite Field in x of size 2^3
sage: V = T.vector_space()
sage: V
Vector space of dimension 3 over Finite Field of size 2
sage: alpha = x^2 + 1
sage: alpha
x^2 + 1
sage: normal_basis = [alpha^(2^i) for i in range(T.degree())]
sage: normal_basis
[x^2 + 1, x^2 + x + 1, x + 1]
```

With `V` as above, field elements transform into vectors as follows.

```
sage: W = [V(b) for b in normal_basis]
sage: W
[(1, 0, 1), (1, 1, 1), (1, 1, 0)]
```

We can then form the corresponding matrix

```
sage: M = matrix(W)
sage: M
[1 0 1]
[1 1 1]
[1 1 0]
```

and compute its inverse

```
sage: ~M
[1 1 1]
[1 1 0]
[0 1 1]
```

Define our symbolic variables.

```
sage: vars = SR.var('a b c')
```

In order to work with symbolic variables, switch
to matrices over `ZZ`.

```
sage: Mz = matrix(ZZ, M)
sage: Mz
[1 0 1]
[1 1 1]
[1 1 0]
```

Multiply on the correct side.

```
sage: vector(vars) * Mz
(a + b + c, b + c, a + b)
```

This expresses that $a(x^2 + 1) + b(x^2 + x + 1) + c(x + 1)$
equals $(a + b + c)1 + (b + c)x + (a + b)x^2$.

Conversely, one would like to know how to express
$a*x^2 + b*x + c$ in the normal basis.

Just invert the matrix.

```
sage: iMz = matrix(ZZ, ~M)
sage: vector(vars) * iMz
(a + b, a + b + c, a + c)
```

This expresses that, in the finite field $T$,
$a + bx + cx^2$ (watch the order) can also be written as
$(a + b)(x^2 + 1) + (a + b + c)(x^2 + x + 1) + (a + c)(x + 1)$.

Summary:

- the matrix `M` and its inverse allow to switch
  from the basis $(1, x, x^2)$ to the basis 
  $(x^2 + 1, x^2 + x + 1, x + 1)$ and back;
- to work with symbolic variables, some gymnastics
  is required, changing from `GF(2)` to `ZZ`, but
  the inverse is computed on the `GF(2)` side.

Regarding what side to multiply matrices and vectors:
we defined `M = matrix(W)`, so we used the vectors in
`W` as rows of `M`. We could instead have defined
`M = column_matrix(W)` and then multiplied matrices
and vectors on the other side.

---

Note: with actual numbers and no symbolic variables,
no need to switch to the `ZZ` side.

Three examples to illustrate this, with notations close to those in the question:

```
sage: def linear_combination(coords, basis):
....:     return sum(c*b for c, b in zip(coords, basis))
....:

sage: gb = (1, 1, 1)
sage: g = linear_combination(gb, normal_basis)
sage: g
1
sage: normal_basis_vector.coordinates(g)
[1, 1, 1]

sage: gb = (1, 0, 1)
sage: g = linear_combination(gb, normal_basis)
sage: g
x^2 + x
sage: normal_basis_vector.coordinates(g)
[1, 0, 1]

sage: gb = (1, 1, 0)
sage: g = linear_combination(gb, normal_basis)
sage: g
x
sage: normal_basis_vector.coordinates(g)
[1, 1, 0]
```

The same three examples, using matrices instead
of `linear_combination` and `.coordinates`:

```
sage: gb = V((1, 1, 1))
sage: g = gb * M
sage: g
(1, 0, 0)
sage: gt = T(g)
sage: gt
1
sage: V(gt)
(1, 0, 0)
sage: V(gt) * ~M
(1, 1, 1)

sage: gb = V((1, 0, 1))
sage: g = gb * M
sage: g
(0, 1, 1)
sage: gt = T(g)
sage: gt
x^2 + x
sage: V(gt)
(0, 1, 1)
sage: V(gt) * ~M
(1, 0, 1)

sage: gb = V((1, 1, 0))
sage: g = gb * M
sage: g
(0, 1, 0)
sage: gt = T(g)
sage: gt
x
sage: V(gt)
(0, 1, 0)
sage: V(gt) * ~M
(1, 1, 0)
```